# Roomba or Create

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Reading old posting and there were (at different time) various discussion on Roomba new/old series XXX, Create and new/older version of the open interface command.

At present time, for learning ROS from zero (with Ubuntu,hard/soft experience), what is best suit? Should I buy the 130 USD  Create as it is cheaper than Roomba at 400USD?

For interfacing the carbo bay connector to ROS Ubuntu computer, is only the RS232 used (analogue and digital pins not used)? How to connect by wireless to desktop PC? How to connect by wire to netbook riding on the robot?

Many thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51248/roomba-or-create/) by [ROS123](https://answers.ros.org/users/3867/ros123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-12-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You will probably find the Create easier to use as it requires less modifications out of the box.  I would also suggest that you look at the [Kobuki](http://www.ros.org/wiki/kobuki) which is designed to be integrated with ROS and has just become available.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-01-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2